# How to use the ls ? option in a bash variable?

Tags: bash, shell, ls, quoting, wildcards

I want to use the ls ? option in a Bash variable.

How do I get the script to do the same thing as `ls -lt foobar_??????.log` ?

```
$ cat foobar_ls.sh 

#!/bin/bash
FOOBAR_LIST="foobar_??????.log"
ls -lt "$FOOBAR_LIST"
```

Here's the prompt version:

```
$ls -lt foobar_??????.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 foobar foobiz 0 Nov  1 14:58 foobar_000003.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 foobar foobiz 0 Nov  1 14:58 foobar_000002.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 foobar foobiz 0 Nov  1 14:58 foobar_000001.log
```

Here's my script version:

```
$ ./foobar_ls.sh 

ls: cannot access foobar_??????.log: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What's in the script then?

Comment: You can't quote wildcards. What your script is doing would be the equivalent of doing this on the command line:  `$ ls -lt "foobar_??????.log"`. Which also wont work.

Comment: @tomas, I 'cat' the script at the top of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me but depending on what you are doing it is probably not a good idea to leave that variable unquoted.  You probably should also use something other than `ls`:  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

**foobar_ls.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
FOOBAR_LIST="foobar_??????.log"
ls -lt ${FOOBAR_LIST}
```

In order to rename these files instead you can do one of the following:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in /path/to/files/foobar_??????.log; do
        mv "$file" "${file}.old"
done
shopt -u nullglob
```

or

```
find /path/to/files -type f -name 'foobar_??????.log' -exec mv {} {}.old \;
```

Comment: If the OP doesn't leave the variable unquoted it won't work as required. This is one of the few situations where quoting a variable is not the right thing to do. Also, I don't see anything that suggests the OP will be parsing `ls`.

Comment: @roaima, me either but I doubt the whole purpose of the script is to list directory contents.  I'm sure he eventually wants to act on this output.

Comment: Correct. I want to rename only the files that meet the wildcard selection.

Comment: @zundarz:  I've updated my answer with some help on how to rename these files as well.

Comment: @zundars if you'd asked that question instead you would have been pointed to a set of answers to do exactly that. None of them would use `ls`.

Answer (score 3):

`?` is not a feature of `ls`, it's a feature of the shell, called [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) or wildcard expansion or pattern matching or [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)). You must let the shell perform the wildcard expansion, so that `ls` receives the list of matching file names.

If you have a string with wildcards in a variable, and you want to expand these wildcards to matching file names, leave the variable substitution unquoted. This is the “split+glob” operator: the value is split into whitespace-delimited parts, and each part is replaced by the list of matching file names, except that parts that don't match any file name are left unmodified.

```
FOOBAR_LIST="foobar_??????.log"
ls -lt $FOOBAR_LIST
```